# python matplotlib legend linestyle '---'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need a way to make matplotlib linestyle '---'. 3's of '-'.

```
character description
'-'       solid line style
'--'      dashed line style
'-.'      dash-dot line style
':'       dotted line style
etc.
```

I can see '-' and '--' in the list, but on the right up side, my legend comes up like " -- red dotted line" (If I write linestyle = '--'). I want '--- red dotted line' on my legend box

Is there any way I can make the legend show three dashes?
Here's what I'm doing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpt

def main():
    mpt.title("hi")
    mpt.xlabel("x axis")
    mpt.ylim([0,50])
    mpt.xlim([0,10])
    mpt.ylabel("y axis")
    mpt.plot([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],'r', linestyle = '???????')
    mpt.legend(["red dotted line"])
    mpt.show()

main()
```

Comment: I don't see difference between your expected `---` and existing `--`. Or maybe you expect dots like with style `:` ?

Comment: @furas oh when I run my code, on the right up side, my legend comes up like " -- red dotted line" (If I write linestyle = '--'). I want '--- red dotted line' on my legend box

Comment: hope that makes sense

Comment: Sounds like what you really need to do is [change the legend](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).

Comment: oh, never thought of that. thanks I'll try that way

Comment: I've edited your comment into the question. When you clarify a question in a comment, it's a good idea also to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mpt.legend(handlelength=3)` and `linestyle='--'`

```
mpt.plot([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],'r', linestyle='--')
mpt.legend(["red dotted line"], handlelength=3)
```